# Почему время выполнения нескольких потоков выше

Tags: java, многопоточность

Пытаюсь разобраться с многопоточностью. Хочу добавить в список числа, которые делятся на 11, 13 и 17 в диапазоне от 10000000 до 40000000. Укажите, пожалуйста, на ошибку, из-за которой время выполнения 3 потоков получается выше, чем если бы все выполнялось в один поток. Спасибо.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date d1 = new Date();
    List<Integer> synlist = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    CounterClass c1 = new CounterClass(10000000, 20000000, synlist);
    CounterClass c2 = new CounterClass(20000001, 30000000, synlist);
    CounterClass c3 = new CounterClass(30000001, 40000000, synlist);
    while (true){
        if(!c1.getTh().isAlive() && !c2.getTh().isAlive() && !c3.getTh().isAlive()){
            Date d2 = new Date();
            long time = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
            System.out.println("Длина списка: " + synlist.size());
            System.out.println("Время выполнения: " + time + " мс");
            break;
        }
    }
}

public class CounterClass implements Runnable {
private int beginIndex;
private int endIndex;
private List list;
private Thread th;

public CounterClass(int beginIndex, int endIndex, List list) {
    this.beginIndex = beginIndex;
    this.endIndex = endIndex;
    this.list = list;
    th = new Thread(this);
    th.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i = beginIndex; i <= endIndex; i++){
        if(i % 11 == 0 || i % 13 == 0 || i % 17 == 0) list.add(i);
    }
}

public Thread getTh() {
    return th;
}
}
```

Comment: попробуйте для эксперимента каждому потоку дать свой список и не синхронизед. Подозреваю, что так как чисел попадающих в списки очень много, потоки часто находятся в ожидании друг друга на списке. А у списка еще и свои накладные расходы и боюсь они в десяток раз больше, чем операция деления. Можно для начала вообще сделать потоки которые количество таких чисел посчитают, без списков.

Comment: Вместо while(true) нужно выполнить просто join() для ваших потоков. Думаю, как раз цикл всё замедляет

Comment: Действительно, нужно добавлять в отдельные списки в каждом потоке, а потом соединить списки в один в основном потоке. Так будет прирост по времени. Спасибо Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас три потока, которые ищут нужные числа в своем диапазоне. Когда один поток нашел число, он пытается добавить его в список методом add(), но перед этим он проверяет, не занят ли метод другим потоком (почитайте про монитор обьектов), если не занят он выполняет метод add(). Если занят, поток помещается в blocked set и ждет, когда другой поток отпустит метод add(). Два или более потоков не могут одновременно добавлять элементы в лист, у вас каждый поток по очереди добавляет элементы, выполняя проверки, или находясь в ожидании освобождения метода, пока другой поток выполняет этот метод.

При однопоточном программировании и без синхронизированных методов, у вас нет этих проверок на то, занят ли метод другим потоком, помещение его в blocked set и т.д.
Так что, как писал @Mike, создайте три листа, которые заполняются отдельными потоками, а затем объедините их.

P.s. Вообще скорость выполнения при многопоточном программировании зависит от многих факторов. От ОС, от количества ядер, JVM и т.д. Так что если одно выполняется быстрее в однопоточке чем в многопоточном на одном компьютере, то на другом компьютере может быть наоборот.